# Different URI for each instance of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITabController with five tabs. Each tab simply holds an instance of a custom UIViewController, and each instance holds a UIWebView.

I want the UIWebView in each tab to open a different URI, but I don't think it should be necessary to create a new class for each tab.

I can make it work if I do `[self.webView loadRequest:]` in `-(void)viewDidLoad` but it seems ridiculous to create five different classes with five different versions of viewDidLoad when all I really want to change is the URI.

Here's what I've tried:

**appDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface elfAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

**appDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    customVC *start = [[customVC alloc] init];
    customVC *eshop = [[customVC alloc] init];
    customVC *table = [[customVC alloc] init];
    customVC *video = [[customVC alloc] init];
    customVC *other = [[customVC alloc] init];

    // Doesn't do anything... I wish it would!
    [start.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[start, eshop, table, video, other];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**customVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customVC : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView* mWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView* webView;

- (void)updateAddress:(NSURLRequest*)request;
- (void)loadAddress:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event;

@end
```

**customVC.m**

```
@interface elfVC ()

@end

@implementation elfVC

@synthesize webView = mWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a property of type `NSURL*` in your customVC.

Change your customVC's `-(id)init` method to `-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url` as follows:

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url{
 self = [super init];
 if(self){ 
  self.<URLPropertyName> = url;
 }
 return self;
}
```

Then call

```
[start.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.<URLPropertyName>]];
```

in `viewDidLoad`

Then when you initialize your different instances of customVC, just use

```
customVC *vc = [customVC alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I must be getting confused somewhere. In _customVC.h_ I've added `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *initURL;`. In _customVC.m_ I've added `@synthesize initURL;` and `-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    [self setInitURL:url];
    return self;
}`. I'm getting the error ‘Init methods must return a type related to the receiver type.' What should I be returning?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I should mention that the error is an _ARC Semantic Issue_. Am I creating my property incorrectly? Should it not be `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *initURL;`?

Comment: I think Xcode was having a bad day. I added an NSLog(@"%@", self); to try and figure out what it was returning, and it mysteriously started working :-/

Comment: Things like this happen sometimes unfortunately:). Just make sure you dont use 'retain' with ARC.

Comment: I'm using ARC, and all of my properties are `(nonatomic, retain)`. Should I be using `(strong)` instead?

Comment: I guess its just a better practice to use strong instead of retain. But really, there is no difference between them while using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are initialising your webview after calling it's `loadRequest:` method. To avoid this, it's a better practice to initialise nonatomic properties by overriding their setters:

```
- (UIWebView*)webview {
    if (mWebView == nil) {
        // do the initialization here
    }
    return mWebView;
}
```

This way your webview will be initialised when you first access it (while calling `loadRequest:`) and not after it, in your custom view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure it really solves my problem, but I appreciate the advice.